# Route MVC ASP.Net just won't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I can't get this work, even after dozens of other similar questions. Here is my controller (created with entity framework)

```
namespace mypage.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("Booking")]
    public class BookingsController : BaseController
    {
        private mypageContext db = new mypageContext();

        // GET: Bookings
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = db.Bookings.ToList();
            //model.Find()
            return View(model);
        }
// etc.
```

my global.asax

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        Database.SetInitializer<mypageContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<mypageContext>());
    }
}
```

And routeconfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

I always get a 404 when opening http://localhost:xxxxx/Booking
this however works http://localhost:xxxxx/Bookings

Is there any other spot to check?

PS: the `BaseController` is just empty

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{

}
```

**Edit**

If I however add instead of RoutePrefix a *regular* Prefix, it doesn't work at all either

```
[Route("Booking/New")]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `Route` attribute for the action if you specify `RoutePrefix` attribute for the controller.

```
[RoutePrefix("TestPrefix")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [Route("TestAction")]
    public ActionResult TestAction()
    {
        //.........
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, followup question, because that actually worked. Do I really need now to add the `[Route("ThisAction")]` to every action?

Comment: You can mark the controller with `[RoutePrefix("Booking"), Route("{action}")]` and won't need it on every action. Lots of examples here [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Comment: If I add for any action this here `[Route("test")]`, I get a `HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request`.... why that?

Comment: Use the relevant action name with `Route` attribute. It will get added to the route table.

Comment: @Isuru, can you elaborate that?

Comment: Ok each and every action in your controller is different and you might be passing parameters to them. So the way you specify `Route` attribute differs. Please refer the link provided by @Jasen. It has some good explanations on this.